# meteor templete adding to another template dynamically

Tags: meteor

How add the template to another template in dynamically when we click on the button. Please help me. Please give me the example if possible.

```
<template name="temp1">
<table>
<tr>

   <td><input  class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" id="add" value="add"/></td>                      

</td>       
</tr>
</table>   
</template>

<template name="temp2">
 <input type="text" value="" name='inp1'/>
</template>
```

when we click on the add button in temp1 wee need to append the temp2 in temp1.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiple ways to do it, but one way

in your js...

```
Template.temp1.events({
  "click #add": function (event, template) {
    Session.set("showtemp2", true);
  },
 });

Template.temp1.helpers({
   showtemp2: function(){ 
     return Session.get("showtemp2");
   }
});
```

in your html

```
<template name="temp1">
<table>
<tr>

   <td><input  class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" id="add" value="add"/></td>                      

</td>       
</tr>
</table>   
{{#if showtemp2}}
{{> temp2}}
{{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Blaze.renderWithData](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_renderwithdata). It allows you to render a template anywhere in the DOM. You need to add an event map for the temp1 that calls it. Remember to give your table an ID (`myTable`):

```
Template.temp1.events({
  "click #add": function (evt) {
    Blaze.renderWithData("temp2", "data", $('table#myTable'), "temp1")
  },
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following code on button click:

```
'click .myButton': function() {
     // empty the element where you want to insert your template.
    $('#myDomElement').empty();

   //insert the template
   UI.render(Template.Mytemplate, $("#myDomElement")[0]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

With Meteor 1.0, there is an in-built helper called Template.dynamic:
https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=dynTemp [data=data] }}
```

You can easily set the dynTemp variable can be reactively set using the Session variable. Maybe something like this:

```
Template.yourTemplate.dynTemp = function() {
    return Session.get("dynTemp", "templateToRender");
}
```

Hope it helps :)